# How to get only two oldest records based on 'date' from first 50 records 'ORDER BY id DESC'

Tags: mysql

I have this query to select the record no 49 and 50

```
SELECT id,date 
FROM table 
WHERE enabled=1 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 2 OFFSET 48
```

Now I want to select records in such a way that

1. Select first 50 records `'ORDER BY id DESC'`
2. Then of these records select 2 oldest records based on `'date'`

My intention is to get only two oldest records based on `'date'` from **first 50 records** `'ORDER BY id DESC'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query

```
SELECT id, date
FROM(
    SELECT id, date
    FROM table
    WHERE enabled = 1
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 50) T1
ORDER BY date ASC
LIMIT 2;
```

Hope this should help you out.

Comment: what is **T1**?

Comment: It is just an alias name to the sub-query

Answer (score 0):

Then use a subquery order by `date` column

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id,
    `date`
     FROM table1 
    WHERE enabled=1 
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50 ) xxx
    ORDER BY `date`
    LIMIT 2;
```